# Nested Search using LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN

Tags: c, active-directory, ldap, nested, ldap-query

I am using LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN to retrieve all nested user-groups to which a user is part of. However, i am facing issue of performance as user is located in a really nested domain forest.

As, a result i am getting too many user-group entries. In order to improve performance, is it possible to restrict the number of entries based on the nested-depth. Say, i would like to fetch all user-groups which user is part of till nested-depth (3-4)?

Server used is :Active Directory (2003/2008)

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

The search happens recursivly so only way to make it faster is limit where you are searching from. ie the search base, make it more specific if you can. No point searching places where you are sure there will be no results.